# intellisense not working in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense

intellisense not working in my system. i am connect to my office server, my office server system is crased then they are change the server system after change the server system, intellisense is not working. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

There are some situations when the IntelliSense does not work. We had faced this situation in past.

- IntelliSense is only available when the Database Engine Query Editor
  is connected to an instance of the Database Engine from SQL Server
  2008 or later. IntelliSense is not available when the Query Editor is
  connected to earlier versions of the Database Engine.
- IntelliSense is turned off in the Database Engine Query Editor when
  the SQLCMD mode is set on.
- IntelliSense functionality does not cover database objects created by
  another connection after your editor window connected to the
  database.

Please review this to troubleshoot for any additional issues.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173434.aspx